# Cannot get file from the external path, is not a valid virtual path. by asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display the images from the path : http://www.ABC.com/images, but it error: http://www.ABC.com/images is not a virtual path. This is my code in the view of aps.net mvc c# :

```
FileInfo[] files = new 
DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("http://www.ABC.com/images/")).GetFiles();
var exefiles = from FileInfo f in files
              where f.Extension == ".jpg"
              select f;

foreach (FileInfo f in exefiles)
            { %>

               <img src="http://www.ABC.com/images/<%:f.Name  %>" alt="" height="239px" width="930px" />
            <% 
            }
```

Anyone know about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible on multiple levels.

`http://www.abc.com` is not a folder on your disk.

Comment: So what should I do if I want to get the source from another site? Thank.

Comment: You need some way to interact with the other server, such as HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Do a HttpWebRequest to http://www.abc.com/images/. Server.MapPath only works for local server virtual paths

Comment: I put it as a sample. The path not in local server.